# ブックマークの後継機能Savesを何と訳すか

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

ブックマークがSavesという名称に変わり、リストの作成やメモの追加など様々な機能が追加されたようです。

[Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019)

このためブックマーク周辺の文章も再度翻訳する必要がありますが、Savesという名称は何と翻訳するのが良いでしょうか？

---

「保存」と訳すと次のような翻訳となりますが、普段「保存」を動詞として使うことが多いからか、違和感があります。また「保存」という単語自体がありふれたものということもあり、名詞として使用すると混乱してしまうケースがあるかもしれません。

- [Save updated](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/16519)：保存を更新した
- [Add a private note to your save (optional)](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/16388)：保存に非公開のメモを追加する（オプション）

私は従来の「ブックマーク」という名称は他サービスでも使用されており直感的でよりわかりやすく感じるため、Savesを「ブックマーク」と置き換えて訳すのが良いと考えています。

Comment: MSE でのアナウンスに対しても反対意見が噴出しているようなので、もう少し様子見で良さそうな気がします。「ブックマーク」の方が良いのであれば、翻訳で無理に維持するのではなく、元の表現でブックマークを継続する方に声を上げた方がよさそうです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[完了](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

#### 「セーブ」を提案します

新機能「Saves」の訳語としてはカタカナ表記の「セーブ」を提案します。

##### ある程度の違和感は受け入れるしかない

旧名称「ブックマーク」の方がよいという意見に100%賛成しますが、翻訳でやるのはリスキーだと感じます。整合性が保てるか不安です。[検索演算子も `in:saves` になる](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3782/3054)とのことですし、あまり飛躍した語は当てられないと思います。

そもそも「saves」は英語としても妙なので、違和感は運営者の決定として受け入れるしか無いかも知れません。

##### カタカナ語でサイト独自の概念だと伝える

「セーブ」は「save(s)」の訳としてゲームなどで使われています。これは十分に膾炙したカタカナ語であり、意味が通じます。カタカナ語に頼り過ぎると変になりますが、あまりにも日常的な「保存」という語を乱用するよりは、かえって違和感が少ないと思います。

また、このサイト独自の機能・概念として「セーブ」というものが有るのだな、と了解しやすくなります。

Comment: こちらのご提案が最も多くプラス投票された状態でしばらく時間が経過したため、一旦「セーブ」で書き換えました。もしもコミュニティの総意が変わったという場合には再度書き換えできればと思います。